# Dynamic content can't be fadedin

Tags: jquery

I'm using history.js to enable going back and forward in history at a website, what it does is that it changes the id and dom contents of ".container .content".

My problem is that whenever this html is inserted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container .content .loggedin').fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>
<p class="notification">
</p><div class="loggedin">
<h1>Welcome, <b>USER</b>.</h1>
</div>
```

the fadeIn isn't doing what it's supposed to do (and the selector is correct), although putting an `alert()` inside the `ready()` works.

Also the div is set to be hidden in the stylesheet, and isn't shown at all.

Comment: Where is the `.container .content` then? I don't see it in your HTML.

Comment: @RichardA its in the dom, this is just a snippet that's inserted into ".containter .content".

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn` animates the opacity. If you set it to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, the div may be hidden despite being opaque, so instead of hiding it using one of the above methods, try `opacity: 0`

Comment: same goes for `show` and `opacity`. Show only toggles the `display` CSS setting.

Comment: show() doesn't set the display property in this case same problems as with fadeIn().